# Is there a difference how to attach session to the query?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to create transaction in mongoose using `withTransaction` helper. As far I understand I can bind session to the mongoose command by using options object (second argument of the function). Also I able to pass session object to the `.session()` function which is also provided by mongoose.

The question is

What is a difference between two approaches? I found that `findByIdAndDelete` returns different result depending on selected approach (see images below). Also I didn't find this issue with other mongoose queries.

[image: Pass session object as option]
Picture 1 - Pass `session` object as option.

[image: Pass session object in separate session function provided by mongoose]
Picture 2 - Pass `session` object to the `.session(session)` function.

Comment: Are the results different when you execute each version?

Comment: @Oleg, the result is shown inside tooltip. At least typescript returns different types.

Comment: What are the documented return types for each of the methods?

Comment: @Oleg, what do you mean under "documented return types"?

Comment: I mean what does the node driver's documentation say about its return types?

Comment: @Oleg, I was not able to find this

Comment: What is your question, then? Does the difference in return types affect your application in some way?

Comment: @Oleg, the question was "What is a difference between these two approaches, which of the is preferred? I wouldn't be asking this question if return types were the same. Yes, by returning different types TypeScript emphasize this part of code as wrong

Comment: MongoDB drivers occasionally provide different spellings to achieve the same result. If all variations are documented as supported, use the one that makes the most sense for your application.